# Jq offline install issue - Centos7

Tags: jenkins, centos7, jq

I am trying to install JQ on to a server that has no access to the internet.

I downloaded the jq-1.5-1.el7.src.rpm file to a machine that is online and transferred it to the online machine.

I then ran rpm -Uvh jq-1.5-1.el7.src.rpm on the offline machine. It says it installed 100% but when I try run jq --version, it says jq is no such file or directory.

Any ideas why?

Output:

- rpm -Uvh jq-1.5-1.el7.src.rpm
  warning: jq-1.5-1.el7.src.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 352c64e5: NOKEY
  Updating / installing...
  1:jq-1.5-1.el7                     ################################# [100%]
  warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
  warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
  warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
  warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is source RPM which isn't built software (binary). You have to build the rpm first.

```
rpmbuild --rebuild jq-1.5-1.el7.src.rpm
```

If things go right, you will end up with package like jq-1.5-1.el7.*.rpm file somewhere in ~/rpmbuild/RPMS/ *. You can then install that rpm.

You can refer to

https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/RebuildSRPM

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110880